# Tools to use for conditional density estimation in Python

Tags: python, kernel-density, probability-density

I have a large data set that contains 3 attributes per row: A,B,C

Column A: can take the values 1, 2, and 0.
Column B and C: can take any values.

I'd like to perform density estimation using histograms for P(A = 2 | B,C) and plot the results using python.

I do not need the code to do it, I can try and figure that on my own. I just need to know the procedures and the tools that should I use?

Comment: Take a stab at it and post your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your over-all question, we should go through different steps and answer different questions:

- How to read csv file (or text data) ?
- How to filter data ?
- How to plot data ?

At each stage, you need to use some techniques and specific tools, you might also have different choices at different stages (You can look on the internet for different alternatives).

1- How to read csv file:

There is a built-in function to go through the csv file where you store your data. But most people recommend [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to deal with csv files.

After [installing Pandas package](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html), you can read your csv file using [Read_CSV](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) command.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

As you didn't share the csv file, I will make a random dataset to explain the up-coming steps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t= [1,1,1,2,0,1,1,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 2), columns=list('AC'))
df['B']=t  #put a random column with only 0,1,2 values, then insert it to the dataframe
```

Note: [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is a python-Package. It's helpful to work with mathematical operations. You don't primarily need it, but I mentioned it to clear confusion here.

In case you print df in this case, you will get as result:

```
         A         C    B
0  -0.090162  0.035458  1
1   2.068328 -0.357626  1
2  -0.476045 -1.217848  1
3  -0.405150 -1.111787  2
4   0.502283  1.586743  0
5   1.822558 -0.398833  1
6   0.367663  0.305023  1
7   2.731756  0.563161  0
8   2.096459  1.323511  0
9   1.386778 -1.774599  2
10 -0.512147 -0.677339  1
11 -0.091165  0.587496  1
12 -0.264265  1.216617  2
13  1.731371 -0.906727  0
14  0.969974  1.305460  0
15 -0.795679 -0.707238  0
16  0.274473  1.842542  0
17  0.771794 -1.726273  1
18  0.126508 -0.206365  1
19  0.622025 -0.322115  1
```

2- - How to filter data: 
There are different techniques to filter data. The easiest one is by selecting the name of column inside your dataframe + the condition. In our case, the criteria is selecting value "2" in column B.

```
l= df[df['B']==2]
print l
```

You can also use other ways such groupby, lambda to go through the data frame and apply different conditions to filter the data.

```
for key in df.groupby('B'):
    print key
```

If you run the above-mentioned scripts you'll get:

For the first one: Only data where B==2

```
           A         C  B
3  -0.405150 -1.111787  2
9   1.386778 -1.774599  2
12 -0.264265  1.216617  2
```

For the second one: Printing the results divided in groups.

```
(0,            A         C  B
4   0.502283  1.586743  0
7   2.731756  0.563161  0
8   2.096459  1.323511  0
13  1.731371 -0.906727  0
14  0.969974  1.305460  0
15 -0.795679 -0.707238  0
16  0.274473  1.842542  0)
(1,            A         C  B
0  -0.090162  0.035458  1
1   2.068328 -0.357626  1
2  -0.476045 -1.217848  1
5   1.822558 -0.398833  1
6   0.367663  0.305023  1
10 -0.512147 -0.677339  1
11 -0.091165  0.587496  1
17  0.771794 -1.726273  1
18  0.126508 -0.206365  1
19  0.622025 -0.322115  1)
(2,            A         C  B
3  -0.405150 -1.111787  2
9   1.386778 -1.774599  2
12 -0.264265  1.216617  2)
```

- How to plot your data:

The simplest ways to plot your data is by using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

The easiest ways to plot data in columns B, is by running :

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xbins=range(0,len(l))
plt.hist(df.B, bins=20, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

You'll get this result:

[image]

if you wanna plot the results combined, you should use different colors/techniques to make it useful.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = df.A
b = df.B
c = df.C
t= range(20)
plt.plot(t, a, 'r--',  b, 'bs--', c, 'g^--')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You'll get as a result:

[image]

Plotting data is driven by a specific need. You can explore the different ways to plot data by going through the examples of [marplotlib.org official website](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html).

Comment: Wow! Your answer was extremely well explained and detailed. Thank you so much! I really appreciate the time you took to answer.

Comment: @OliverHoffman: Glad you find the answer helpful! :) Good Luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for other tools that do slightly more sophisticated things than nonparametric density estimation with histograms, please check this [link](https://github.com/freelunchtheorem/Conditional_Density_Estimation) to the python repository or directly install the package with

```
pip install cde
```

In addition to an extensive documentation, the package implements

- **Nonparametric** (conditional & neighborhood kernel density estimation)
- **semiparametric** (least squares cde) and
- **parametric neural network**-based methods (mixture density networks, kernel density estimation)

Also, the package allows to compute centered moments, statistical divergences (kl-divergence, hellinger, jensen-shannon), percentiles, expected shortfalls and data generating processes (arma-jump, jump-diffusion, GMMs etc.)

Disclaimer: I am one of the package developers.