# Pandas groupby month and year

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date        abc    xyz
01-Jun-13   100    200
03-Jun-13   -20    50
15-Aug-13   40     -5
20-Jan-14   25     15
21-Feb-14   60     80
```

I need to group the data by year and month. I.e., Group by Jan 2013, Feb 2013, Mar 2013, etc...

I will be using the newly grouped data to create a plot showing abc vs xyz per year/month.

I've tried various combinations of groupby and sum, but I just can't seem to get anything to work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can use either resample or `Grouper` (which resamples under the hood).

First make sure that the datetime column is actually of datetimes (hit it with `pd.to_datetime`). It's easier if it's a DatetimeIndex:

```
In [11]: df1
Out[11]:
            abc  xyz
Date
2013-06-01  100  200
2013-06-03  -20   50
2013-08-15   40   -5
2014-01-20   25   15
2014-02-21   60   80

In [12]: g = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))  # DataFrameGroupBy (grouped by Month)

In [13]: g.sum()
Out[13]:
            abc  xyz
Date
2013-06-30   80  250
2013-07-31  NaN  NaN
2013-08-31   40   -5
2013-09-30  NaN  NaN
2013-10-31  NaN  NaN
2013-11-30  NaN  NaN
2013-12-31  NaN  NaN
2014-01-31   25   15
2014-02-28   60   80

In [14]: df1.resample("M", how='sum')  # the same
Out[14]:
            abc  xyz
Date
2013-06-30   40  125
2013-07-31  NaN  NaN
2013-08-31   40   -5
2013-09-30  NaN  NaN
2013-10-31  NaN  NaN
2013-11-30  NaN  NaN
2013-12-31  NaN  NaN
2014-01-31   25   15
2014-02-28   60   80
```

Note: Previously `pd.Grouper(freq="M")` was written as `pd.TimeGrouper("M")`. The latter is now deprecated since 0.21.

---

I had thought the following would work, but it doesn't (due to `as_index` not being respected? I'm not sure.). I'm including this for interest's sake.

If it's a column (it has to be a datetime64 column! as I say, hit it with `to_datetime`), you can use the PeriodIndex:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
        Date  abc  xyz
0 2013-06-01  100  200
1 2013-06-03  -20   50
2 2013-08-15   40   -5
3 2014-01-20   25   15
4 2014-02-21   60   80

In [22]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date).to_period("M")  # old way
Out[22]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
[2013-06, ..., 2014-02]
Length: 5, Freq: M

In [23]: per = df.Date.dt.to_period("M")  # new way to get the same

In [24]: g = df.groupby(per)

In [25]: g.sum()  # dang not quite what we want (doesn't fill in the gaps)
Out[25]:
         abc  xyz
2013-06   80  250
2013-08   40   -5
2014-01   25   15
2014-02   60   80
```

To get the desired result we have to reindex...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I couldn't get TimeGrouper to work, but resample("M") did the trick. However just fyi, it required the argument how='sum'. My only problem now is that the plot is using the full datetime for the tick labels. I need it to just show the month and year for each bar. Thanks again.

Comment: note that `TimeGrouper` [is now deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0210-deprecations). The code `df1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M"))` should now be `df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))`

Comment: Why there are so many 'NaN's in the results? And the resultant `Date` column has the last day of a month which seems to be an arbitrary choice, why not the 1st day, or not giving the day at all?

Comment: @jason you can use 'MS' to use month start. Lots of NaN because the sample has no data in those months...

Comment: It seems like your results are wrong. First example indicates 2013-06-30   80  250 but then second example indicates 2013-06-30   40  125 which the results are halved. Why is that so?

Answer (score 110):

Keep it simple:

```
GB = DF.groupby([(DF.index.year), (DF.index.month)]).sum()
```

giving you,

```
print(GB)
        abc  xyz
2013 6   80  250
     8   40   -5
2014 1   25   15
     2   60   80
```

and then you can plot like asked using,

```
GB.plot('abc', 'xyz', kind='scatter')
```

Comment: This one! Good answer. More intuitive - pull the month from the index as a number, create a grouping of all indexes with the same month, and calculate based around those groups. Just learning pandas so this is intuitive.

Comment: Alternative solution for newer versions of Pandas:

    `GB=DF.groupby([DF.index.year.values,DF.index.month.values]).sum()`

Comment: DF.index.dt.year, DF.index.dt.month

Comment: This seems simpler than the accepted answer. I had to use `DF.column.dt.year` though to group by a column.

Comment: @Q-man: But how do you then set the index back to a datetime object?

Comment: @PEBKAC - the output of `GB` now has a multi-index - you can now reset the index to a new monthly period index.

Answer (score 11):

There are different ways to do that.

- I created the data frame to showcase the different techniques to filter your data.

  ```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-Jun-13', '03-Jun-13', '15-Aug-13', '20-Jan-14', '21-Feb-14'],
                       'abc': [100, -20, 40, 25, 60], 'xyz': [200, 50,-5, 15, 80] })
  ```
- I separated months/year/day and separated month-year as you explained.

  ```
    def getMonth(s):
        return s.split("-")[1]

    def getDay(s):
        return s.split("-")[0]

    def getYear(s):
        return s.split("-")[2]

    def getYearMonth(s):
        return s.split("-")[1] + "-" + s.split("-")[2]
  ```
- I created new columns: `year`, `month`, `day` and '`yearMonth`'. In your case, you need one of both. You can group using two columns `'year','month'` or using one column `yearMonth`

  ```
    df['year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: getYear(x))
    df['month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: getMonth(x))
    df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: getDay(x))
    df['YearMonth'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: getYearMonth(x))
  ```

  Output:

  ```
          Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  0  01-Jun-13  100  200   13   Jun  01    Jun-13
  1  03-Jun-13  -20   50   13   Jun  03    Jun-13
  2  15-Aug-13   40   -5   13   Aug  15    Aug-13
  3  20-Jan-14   25   15   14   Jan  20    Jan-14
  4  21-Feb-14   60   80   14   Feb  21    Feb-14
  ```
- You can go through the different groups in groupby(..) items.

  In this case, we are grouping by two columns:

  ```
    for key, g in df.groupby(['year', 'month']):
        print key, g
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  ('13', 'Jun')         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  0  01-Jun-13  100  200   13   Jun  01    Jun-13
  1  03-Jun-13  -20   50   13   Jun  03    Jun-13
  ('13', 'Aug')         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  2  15-Aug-13   40   -5   13   Aug  15    Aug-13
  ('14', 'Jan')         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  3  20-Jan-14   25   15   14   Jan  20    Jan-14
  ('14', 'Feb')         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  ```

  In this case, we are grouping by one column:

  ```
    for key, g in df.groupby(['YearMonth']):
        print key, g
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Jun-13         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  0  01-Jun-13  100  200   13   Jun  01    Jun-13
  1  03-Jun-13  -20   50   13   Jun  03    Jun-13
  Aug-13         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  2  15-Aug-13   40   -5   13   Aug  15    Aug-13
  Jan-14         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  3  20-Jan-14   25   15   14   Jan  20    Jan-14
  Feb-14         Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  4  21-Feb-14   60   80   14   Feb  21    Feb-14
  ```
- In case you want to access a specific item, you can use `get_group`

  ```
    print df.groupby(['YearMonth']).get_group('Jun-13')
  ```

  Output:

  ```
          Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  0  01-Jun-13  100  200   13   Jun  01    Jun-13
  1  03-Jun-13  -20   50   13   Jun  03    Jun-13
  ```
- Similar to `get_group`. This hack would help to filter values and get the grouped values.

  This also would give the same result.

  ```
    print df[df['YearMonth']=='Jun-13']
  ```

  Output:

  ```
          Date  abc  xyz year month day YearMonth
  0  01-Jun-13  100  200   13   Jun  01    Jun-13
  1  03-Jun-13  -20   50   13   Jun  03    Jun-13
  ```

  You can select list of `abc` or `xyz` values during `Jun-13`

  ```
    print df[df['YearMonth']=='Jun-13'].abc.values
    print df[df['YearMonth']=='Jun-13'].xyz.values
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [100 -20]  #abc values
  [200  50]  #xyz values
  ```

  You can use this to go through the dates that you have classified as "year-month" and apply criteria on it to get related data.

  ```
    for x in set(df.YearMonth):
        print df[df['YearMonth']==x].abc.values
        print df[df['YearMonth']==x].xyz.values
  ```

I recommend also to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558576/conditional-probability-density-estimation-in-python/26559206#26559206) as well.

Comment: For anyone whose dates are in this format `2016-08-11`, change `def getYearMonth(s):
  return s.split("-")[1]+"-"+s.split("-")[2]` to def getYearMonth(s):
  return s.split("-")[0]+"-"+s.split("-")[1]` to get output of `2016-08`

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it by creating a string column with the year and month as follows:

```
df['date'] = df.index
df['year-month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: str(x.year) + ' ' + str(x.month))
grouped = df.groupby('year-month')
```

**However** this doesn't preserve the order when you loop over the groups, e.g.

```
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
```

Will give:

```
2007 11
2007 12
2008 1
2008 10
2008 11
2008 12
2008 2
2008 3
2008 4
2008 5
2008 6
2008 7
2008 8
2008 9
2009 1
2009 10
```

So then, if you want to preserve the order, you must do as suggested by @Q-man above:

```
grouped = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])
```

This will preserve the order in the above loop:

```
(2007, 11)
(2007, 12)
(2008, 1)
(2008, 2)
(2008, 3)
(2008, 4)
(2008, 5)
(2008, 6)
(2008, 7)
(2008, 8)
(2008, 9)
(2008, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers are using `Date` as an index instead of a column (and there's nothing wrong with doing that).

However, for anyone who has the dates stored as a column (instead of an index), remember to access the column's `dt` attribute. That is:

```py
# First make sure `Date` is a datetime column
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(
  arg=df['Date'],
  format='%d-%b-%y' # Assuming dd-Mon-yy format
)

# Group by year and month
df.groupby(
  [
    df['Date'].dt.year,
    df['Date'].dt.month 
  ]
).sum()
```

Comment: This gives me the error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" even though my date column is a DateTime array

Answer (score 0):

A simple and more generic method is to create a column that gives the bins you want the data in. For this problem, the bins will be years and months. Note that since you are plotting the result, you don't need to include months with no data.

The index will be converted to a datetime index, and will be used to create the bins. The `groupby` method removes the column when processing the bins, which become the rows in the index. Optionally the index can be converted to a datetime index again at the end, allowing proper sorts.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = ['01-Jun-13', '03-Jun-13', '15-Aug-13', '20-Jan-14', '21-Feb-14']
data = {'abc': [100, -20, 40, 25, 60],
        'xyz': [200, 50, -5, 15, 80]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, data=data)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%b-%y')
df['bin'] = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-01')
result = df.groupby('bin').sum()
result.index = pd.to_datetime(result.index)
```

`df` and `result` are now:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
            abc  xyz         bin
2013-06-01  100  200  2013-06-01
2013-06-03  -20   50  2013-06-01
2013-08-15   40   -5  2013-08-01
2014-01-20   25   15  2014-01-01
2014-02-21   60   80  2014-02-01

In [2]: result
Out[2]: 
            abc  xyz
bin                 
2013-06-01   80  250
2013-08-01   40   -5
2014-01-01   25   15
2014-02-01   60   80
```