# getting mean() used in groupby to use the right grouped values for calculation

Tags: python, pandas

Data import from csv:

| Date | Item_1 | Item 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990-01-01 | 34 | 78 |
| 1990-01-02 | 42 | 19 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| 2020-12-31 | 41 | 23 |

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Insert file directory')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
gb= df.groupby([(df.index.year),(df.index.month)]).mean()
```

Issue:
So basically, the requirement is to group the data according to year and month before processing and I thought that the groupby function would have grouped the data so that the mean() calculate the averages of all values grouped under Jan-1990, Feb-1990 and so on. However, I was wrong. The output result in the average of all values under Item_1


My example is similar to the below post but in my case, it is calculating the mean. I am guessing that it has to do with the way the data is arranged after groupby or some parameters in mean() have to be specified but I have no idea which is the cause. Can someone enlighten me on how to correct the code?

[Pandas groupby month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646191/pandas-groupby-month-and-year)

Update:
Hi all, I have created the sample data file .csv with 3 items and 3 months of data. I am wondering if the cause has to do with the conversion of data into df when it is imported from .csv because I have noticed some weird time data on the leftmost as shown below:

[image]

Link to sample file is:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/t81wh3zem6vf4c2/test.csv/file

Comment: Your code seems to work correctly for me. Perhaps you can add a bit more detail to drill down on the problem.

Comment: Hi bicarlsen, I have recreated the sample data in the same file format (link is provided above) and update the code to show how I import the .csv file into the df. I have tried to run the code again and it still calculates the average of entire values under each item.

Comment: @user14074078 have you tested [my proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730009/16343464)?

Comment: @mozway yes, I have tried your proposed solution and the result is the same. I am wondering if the conversion of csv, resulted in some unwanted item being included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv( 'test.csv', index_col = 'date' )
df.index = pd.to_datetime( df.index )

df.groupby([(df.index.year),(df.index.month)]).mean()
```

Seems to do the trick from the provided data.

Comment: Hi bicarlsen, inclusion of the argument, index_col = 'date', works! Thanks for your help!!! Really appreciate it. Once again, I am caught-off guard by small details in code, lol.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to calculate the mean of all elements. You can use numpy's mean function that operates on the flattened array by default:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')
gb = df.groupby([(df.index.year),(df.index.month)]).apply(lambda d: np.mean(d.values))
```

output:

```
date  date
1990  1       0.563678
      2       0.489105
      3       0.459131
      4       0.755165
      5       0.424466
      6       0.523857
      7       0.612977
      8       0.396031
      9       0.452538
      10      0.527063
      11      0.397951
      12      0.600371
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi mozway, I have recreated the sample data in the same file format (link is provided above) and update the code to show how I import the .csv file into the df. I have tried to run the code again and it still calculates the average of entire values under each item.

Comment: @user14074078 I updated the code. Apparently, this works only on the raw array.

Comment: Hi mozway, I have tried your updated code, it results in "ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)"

However, bicarlsen's slight alteration to the argument for pd.read_csv seems to do the trick. Once again, thank you for your assistance in this. Really appreciate it!