# How to search pandas data frame by index value and value in any column

Tags: python, pandas, selection

I am trying to select data, read in from a file, represented by the values one and zero. I want to be able to select rows from a list of values and at the same time select for any column in which each of the selected rows has a value of one. To make it more complex I also want to select rows from a list of values where all values in a column for these rows is zero. Is this possible? Ultimately if another method besides pandas data frame would work better I would be willing to try that.

To be clear, any column may be selected and I do not know which ones ahead of time.

Thanks!

Comment: Can your provide some example data, together with the desired output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `all()` `any()` `iloc[]` operators. Check the [official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/10min.html), or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558576/conditional-probability-density-estimation-in-python/26559206#26559206) for more details

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np


# Created a dump data as you didn't provide one
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':  [random.getrandbits(1) for i in range(10)], 'col2':  [random.getrandbits(1) for i in range(10)], 'col3': [1]*10})
print(df)

# You can select the value directly by using iloc[] operator
# df.iloc to select by postion .loc to  Selection by Label
row_indexer,column_indexer=3,1
print(df.iloc[row_indexer,column_indexer])

# You can filter the data of a specific column this way
print(df[df['col1']==1])
print(df[df['col2']==1])

# Want to be able to select rows from a list of values and at the same time select for any column in which each of the selected rows has a value of one.
print(df[(df.T == 1).any()])

# If you wanna filter a specific columns with a condition on rows
print(df[(df['col1']==1)|(df['col2']==1)])

# To make it more complex I also want to select rows from a list of values where all values in a column for these rows is zero.
print(df[(df.T == 0).all()])

# If you wanna filter a specific columns with a condition on rows
print(df[(df['col1']==0) & (df['col2']==0)])
```

Comment: I think we're trying to encourage people to use `.loc` or `.iloc` instead of `.ix` these days, because of `.ix`'s hard-to-explain semantics.

Comment: Good point @DSM **.loc/.iloc** were introduced in 0.11 and encouraged to be used for user indexing choice.